# Is it safe to unescape newlines and line breaks?

Tags: php, mysql-real-escape-string

Is it safe to sanitize the input with mysql_real_escape_string and then unescape line-breaks?
For example:

```
$to_database = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['some_input']);
$to_database = str_replace('\n', "\n", $to_database);
$to_database = str_replace('\r', "\r", $to_database);
```

I need this, because they spoil my markdown which is stored in database.

Comment: Couldn't you just use stripslashes on the text when you pull it out of the database?

Comment: It shouldn't make any difference - what is probably happening is some slashes are being added when you read it back out, or slashes are being added into the $_POST var before you store it.

Comment: Stripping slashes would turn `\n` into `n`, which is rather useless... `New line\n` is not the same as `New linen`.

Comment: It is, in fact, remarkably less comfortable. :) Also, since string escaping escapes line breaks, stripping slashes would remove the escaping slash and leave only the regular metacharacter slash. At least that's how it worked so far in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

To unescape special characters like '\n' or '\r' you need use stripcslashes (not stripslashes) after pulling from database

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in unescaping anything after the mysql_real_escape_string. If the data is not read correcly back, most likely magic quotes is turned on. In that case, you have to stripslashes before the escaping. (But do this only if magic quotes is turned on - you can check this at runtime)